# MacOS on M1 kills every ping

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, apple-silicon, path

I'm finding I'm unable to ping addresses like I'm used to on my M1 Macbook Pro. MacOS just kills the process immediately. When I run the process from `/sbin`, it works fine. I can see `/sbin` in my `PATH`. What can I do to make `ping` normally accessible?

```
❯ ping bbc.co.uk

[1]    35435 killed     ping bbc.co.uk

❯ sudo ping bbc.co.uk

[1]    35441 killed     sudo ping bbc.co.uk

❯ /sbin/ping bbc.co.uk

PING bbc.co.uk (151.101.0.81): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.0.81: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=3.786 ms

❯ echo $PATH;

/Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/administrator/Library/pnpm:/Users/administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/inetutils/libexec/gnubin:/Users/administrator/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/administrator/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/administrator/shell-scripts:/Users/administrator/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: What does 'which ping' show?

Comment: Can you run `for p in ${PATH//:/\ }; do [[ -x "$p/ping" ]] && file "$p/ping"; done` and add the result to the question? Also, what does `arch` return and do you have installed Rosetta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have installed an extra `ping` program besides the standard program included in macOS. Most likely the extra `ping` program has not been signed correctly, and thus every attempt at running it will see it killed before doing anything of value.

I would recommend uninstalling the extra `ping` program. You can see where it is located by running the command `type ping`.

For now, you can fix the issue by moving `/sbin` to the front of your `PATH`. This will ensure that the Apple-provided `ping` program is run when you type out the `ping` command - instead of the third party version.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was it! I had `/usr/local/bin/ping` and ``/usr/local/bin/ping6`, which I must've installed some time in the past in the MBP I migrated from. Moving this other `ping` out of that directory fixed the problem.